# SQL: Count of matches in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to find the number of expressions matched in WHERE clause for a SELECT statement. Sample data and table is as follows:

```
    declare @var1 varchar(10), @var2 varchar(10), @var3 varchar(10)
set @var1 = 'a'
set @var2 = null
set @var3 = 'c'
insert into tempTable values(1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
insert into tempTable values(2, 'a', 'e', 'c')
insert into tempTable values(3, 'g', 'b', 'c')

select id from tempTable
where   ISNULL(@var1, colA) = colA
AND     ISNULL(@var2, colB) = colB
AND     ISNULL(@var3, colC) = colC
```

The output should be like this:

```
 id     MatchingCount
 ------------------------
1       2  (because @var1 and @var3 are matched)
2       2  (because @var1 and @var3 are matched)
```

thanks.

Comment: Why is `ID` 3 is not part of result ?

Comment: ID 3 is not part of result,because @var1 is not same as 'colA' of 'tempTable' for ID 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, cast ((case when @var1 = colA then 1 else 0 end) as int) 
          +cast ((case when @var2 = colB then 1 else 0 end) as int)
          +cast ((case when @var3= colC then 1 else 0 end) as int) as MatchCount
from tempTable
```

Use Case

Comment: thanks. it is working with small changes. I have to remove ISNULL checking in SELECT statement.

Comment: it is returning this because of isnull. Remove it then you will have the right results

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve the same from the below query, I think it's better for your requirement and you can easily implement this:

```
SELECT id, 
 SUM((CASE WHEN @var1 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN @var2 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN @var3 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) cnt  
FROM #tempTable
GROUP BY id
```

Without group by,

```
SELECT id, 
    ((CASE WHEN @var1 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN @var2 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN @var3 IN (colA, ColB, ColC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) cnt  
FROM #tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it can help you

```
declare @var1 varchar(10), @var2 varchar(10), @var3 varchar(10)
set @var1 = 'a'
set @var2 = null
set @var3 = 'c'
SELECT t.id,count(t.id) as MatchingCount FROM(
    select id from tempTable
    where   ISNULL(@var1, colA) = colA
    UNION ALL 
    select id from tempTable
    where   ISNULL(@var2, colB) = colB 
    UNION ALL 
    select id from tempTable
    where   ISNULL(@var3, colC) = colC 
) as t GROUP BY id
```